# Reverse order of columns in CSS grid

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the website to have the columns, reverse in the second grid, so that the image and the text is flipped and exchange their positions. I want the elements to change their order. I basically want the layout in the first picture, but no settings are changed. For some reason even when I add a border radius to the image class it isn't working as well.

What I want to achieve:

[image: expected]

What I currently have is this.

[image: my website]

```css
.about_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.grid-container {
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 4rem;
  }
}

.grid-container {
  max-width: 75vw;
}

.section-title {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.title_name {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.title_underline {
  text-align: left;
  background: #F4D06F;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
}

.title_text {
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: grey;
}

.about-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.about_img {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .about_img-flip {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <article class="about-container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae! Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem
          fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image">
        <img src="img/cheeseclose.jpg" class="about__img" alt="about-img">
      </div>
    </article>
    <!--about column 1-->

    <article class="about-container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae! Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem
          fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image">
        <img src="img/cheesedish.jpg" class="about__img about_img-flip" alt="about-img">
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <!--grid container-->
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you have to add one parent class to your section like in my example i have taken `grid-row`.

Now when you want to change the order of the grid element you must need `display: grid;` which you already have it in your `.grid-container` class.

So now we have to set which element you want to show case first in my example i have change the order of `title` to second with help of `grid-row` property.

Check the snippet from the output.

```css
.about_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.grid-container {
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}
.about-container.grid-row .title {
  grid-row: 2;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 4rem;
  }
}

.grid-container {
  max-width: 75vw;
}

.section-title {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.title_name {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.title_underline {
  text-align: left;
  background: #F4D06F;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
}

.title_text {
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: grey;
}

.about-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.about_img {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <article class="about-container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae! Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem
          fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="about__img" alt="about-img">
      </div>
    </article>
    <!--about column 1-->

    <article class="about-container grid-row">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae! Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem
          fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="about__img about_img-flip" alt="about-img">
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <!--grid container-->
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.about_img{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}


.grid-container{
    max-width: 90vw;
    margin: 2rem auto;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
    .grid-container{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
        grid-column-gap: 4rem;
    }
}

.grid-container{
    max-width: 75vw;
}

.section-title{
    padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.title_name{
    font-size: 3rem;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

.title_underline{
    text-align: left;
    background: #F4D06F;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 0.25rem;
}

.title_text{
    letter-spacing: .1rem;
    line-height: 1.5;
    margin-top: 1rem;
    color: grey;
}

.about-container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 100%;
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.about_img{
    border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.order-1 {
  order: 1;
}

.order-2 {
  order: 2;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px){
  .about_img-flip{
    order: -1;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width:768px){

  .order-1 {
    order: 2 !important;
  }

  .order-2 {
    order: 1 !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<section class="about">
  <div class="grid-container">
<article class="about-container">
    <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae!
          Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
<div class="about_image">
    <img src="img/cheeseclose.jpg" class="about__img" alt="about-img">
</div>
</article><!--about column 1-->

<article class="about-container">
    <div class="title order-2">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae!
          Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image order-1">
          <img src="img/cheesedish.jpg" class="about__img about_img-flip" alt="about-img">
      </div>
</article>
</div><!--grid container-->
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Change `order` on both columns. I have kept the order same as it was on small devices. Hope it'll help

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be achieved by adding another class `reverse` to your second `about-container` element. The added CSS is as follows:

```
.about-container.reverse .title {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.about-container.reverse .about_img {
  grid-row: 1;
}
```

Whole code snippet:

```css
.about_img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.grid-container {
  max-width: 90vw;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-column-gap: 4rem;
  }
}

.grid-container {
  max-width: 75vw;
}

.section-title {
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
}

.title_name {
  font-size: 3rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.title_underline {
  text-align: left;
  background: #F4D06F;
  width: 5rem;
  height: 0.25rem;
}

.title_text {
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  color: grey;
}

.about-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2rem;
}

.about-container.reverse .title {
  grid-row: 2;
}

.about-container.reverse .about_img {
  grid-row: 1;
}

.about_img {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .about_img-flip {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="about">
  <div class="grid-container">
    <article class="about-container">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae! Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem
          fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image">
        <img src="img/cheeseclose.jpg" class="about__img" alt="about-img">
      </div>
    </article>
    <!--about column 1-->

    <article class="about-container reverse">
      <div class="title">
        <h1 class="title_name">our story</h1>
        <div class="title_underline"></div>
        <p class="title_text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Veritatis et, doloremque blanditiis tempora deserunt repudiandae! Reprehenderit amet reiciendis recusandae odio. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi voluptatem
          fugiat provident labore animi quidem beatae molestiae voluptates officia odit mollitia</p>
      </div>
      <div class="about_image">
        <img src="img/cheesedish.jpg" class="about__img about_img-flip" alt="about-img">
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
  <!--grid container-->
</section>
```

Comment: For what reason am I not able to change the edges of the image? i keep adding a border radius and nothing changes...